# Arrays have direct support in the CLR

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, clr, il

In "C# in depth" by Jon Skeet I'm reading that (p. 511):

> All arrays derive from System.Array, and they're the only collections with *direct support in the CLR* (My emphasis).

I am wondering what this means exactly, especially in relation to types that don't have this support.
Are all types that don't have this support assembled from types that do by the CLR when it interprets IL? Are types that don't have this support not "known" by the CLR?

Also on p. 512 of the book:

> The C# compiler has built-in support for arrays in a number of ways.

Does this in some way relate to the *direct support* the Array type has in the CLR or are these two separate things altogether?

Comment: Seems silly to attempt an answer when Mr Skeet himself can probably offer a far better answer... :)

Comment: Have a look at [List of CIL instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions). There are a lot of opcodes that deal with arrays, but none that deal with other collections.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As described, arrays exist deep in the CLR. There are IL instructions for interacting with them (`ldelem.*` / `stelem.*`). They pre-date generics, and yet allow arrays of different types to be created as required. This is not the case for other collection types - for example, `List<T>` is a wrapper that exists *on top of* an array. The CLR does not need any special knowledge of `List<T>` - just regular IL that accesses the contents of existing arrays, or allocates new arrays. The other main form of collection is linked lists (and similar; trees, etc) - but again, these don't need special support - these are just objects that connect together with references.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the triad of compiler, jitter and CLR have lots of built-in knowledge of arrays.  This is rather essential for any language runtime, it cannot ignore the capabilities of the processor.  To make code run efficiently, it must map to what a processor can do well.

Which is not a lot, processors are rather simple devices.  They offer no real support for the kind of data structures you like to use in a program.  The way a language and runtime is designed shows lots of underlying processor implementation details.

The notion of a stack is present *everywhere* for example.  A small amount of memory that a processor can access directly through its stack pointer.  Which is why the C# language, as almost any language, has the notion of a local variable inside a method.  That's a variable that's going to be stored on the stack.  The processor also strongly supports the notion of calling methods with arguments that return a single value, about universal in any language.  The small amount of memory allocated for the stack gave this site its name.

Value types are another .NET example of underlying processor detail.  They directly map to what a processor is good at when handling values.  An *int* directly maps to processor register for example.  Float and double directly map to the processor's ability to store those values and execute floating point instructions using those two types.

And an array is the one and only data structure that a processor can support.  Very simple, a chunk of memory with a pointer to access that memory.  *Very* heavily optimized in .NET to make that as efficient as possible.  With a particular nod to "vector", an array type that's treated specially.  A one-dimensional array with a starting index of 0, the array type that directly maps to processor support.  You get a vector in C# with the `type[]` declaration.  You also see the array restrictions back from that, .NET makes if very difficult to create an array with a starting index that is not 0.  For a very good reason, indexing such an array is expensive since it requires an extra subtraction to map the index to the chunk of memory.  The array index check is another strong target for optimization, bounds checking is expensive.  Lots of smarts built-in to the jitter to recognize that a loop can never index an array out of bounds, allowing the index check to be completely eliminated.

Any data structure needs to be built on top of the processor support for just bare arrays.  Which is why you find that done inside the .NET collection classes.  With no extra help from the CLR or jitter since there's little that they can do to make it faster.  Also the reason that these collection classes are all constructed on top of vector arrays.  Like List<>, not a list that resembles the kind you see in your data algorithm text book at all, actually an array.  Or Dictionary<>, the antipode of an array but still implemented with them.

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate answer. Makes the concepts a lot more clear.